# angularjs doesnt send request to backend(uwsgi) in firefox but works well with chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, flask, uwsgi

I have a pretty big application so i am not able to post the code here.
My front end is `angularjs` and backend is `python-flask` . My problem is i have started noticing for some end-points or functions in flask i am getting error in the front-end itself whereas when i check the uwsgi logs i dont even find that access request. This happens only when i try to access the webpage in `firefox` but works perfectly with `chrome`. I face this error with different different functions of flask but the thing is it works when i refresh again and appears after some more tries. So it comes and goes occasionally and i am not able to understand or figure out why. There is no issue with the CORS thing. Has anybody dealt with similar kind of issue? 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[Here is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhKPW.png)

Comment: is there any errors in the browser console

Comment: What does network card from debugger say?

Comment: ok i solved it by using nginx. When i use nginx i dont get any such errors